# Microsoft Win32 to Microsoft .NET Framework API Map

Tags: .net, api, winapi, dictionary

all of we know the .net api is wrapper for win32 api

now how can  i find which .net function  map  in which win32 function

i seen this list http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302340.aspx

but i need to know other function

if i need any tool?

Comment: What exactly are you missing ? The MSDN article is pretty much complete

Comment: Great Link! Thanks. What else do you miss?

Answer (score 1):

The .Net classes are not just a wrapper for Windows APIs. There is certain functionality in .Net that does not have equivalent in Windows APIs. Some .Net classes offer methods that encapsulate the functionality of multiple Windows APIs. And there are Windows APIs that are not exposed as .Net classes and need to be accessed through COM or P/Invoke from .Net.

The MSDN article you link to is rather good map for .Net 1.1. However, both Windows and .Net have changed quite a lot since then. There is no similar list of mappings between .Net 4.0 and Windows Vista or Windows 7.

If you need to know the equivalent of particular Windows API in .Net or vice versa, you should ask specifically about that API. Also, keep in mind that depending on your particular scenario, the actual answer might differ.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/)?  Its a wiki that has almost every signature and type definition for Win32 API calls.